# How do I test to see if there is someone in a role in Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been assigned to make a bot that can make a simple word association game. I also need help making it so that a bot command can be used 3 times (guess) per round, I assume I have to add to a variable, and then have that switch to the next team. It has to be able to allow 1 hint, then 3 guesses, then the next team goes, who has a list of 10 words. If the team can't guess it, when the team gets another turn, they must do the same word again. Whoever gets through all the words first wins. I already have something set up to create a list of 30 words displayed to the players, but I have to make sure the lists of 10 that the bot PMs to the people in RedLeader and BlueLeader roles I'm testing for don't have duplicate words.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: https://repl.it/@FuryWings/discord-bot
Here it is so far.
Thanks.